# How Can I Style a Lightning Component with Bootstrap Styling?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, lightning-apps, css3

I have a question regarding styling Lightning components. On several occasions lately, I have found myself having to opt for the use of a standard HTML tag styled with bootstrap on which I call core Javascript methods instead of the native Lightning ones. The reason for this is a lot of the native Lightning component styling doesn't look as good as the Bootstrap styling. I am wondering if there is a way to simply style a native Lightning component like `<ui:inputSelect>` to look like something like [this](http://jquery-plugins.net/image/plugin/bootstrap-dropdown-hover-plugin.png) instead of the native style that looks more bland and gray, at least on the desktop app.

I would like to keep the functionality of using `cmp.get("v.options")` to get the component options and use the functions mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ui_select.htm?search_text=ui) to populate the list dynamically using Lightning patterns, but I'm stuck on the styling aspect, providing that I don't reapply each individual bootstrap CSS property one-by-one.

Comment: Have you gone through the [Lightning Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/lightning_components) module in Trailhead? There's a section there on Defining Component Attributes where they nest multiple components. Perhaps going through that might give you some ideas on how to accomplish your desired goal without bloating your component. Everything I've seen always uses a separate Style Sheet for each Component Bundle. But, I'm also just getting started with learning.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yeah, the problem is that the native Lightning components such as <ui:button> have so much default styles, it would take a long time to override the all. Currently, I am just having to use the default <button class="btn btn-default"></button> tags so that I can use Bootstrap styling. It just prevents me from using the native Lightning components.

Comment: There's been a huge number of posts in the [Developer Relations Blog](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations) with Lightning project examples that included a lot of code. I highly recommend you go there and run a search. You may find exactly what you're looking for. @PeterKnolle is also having a Lightning [Live Coding Session](https://www.livecoding.tv/peterknolle/) this Sat at 8AM eastern.

Comment: @Daniel, "how to style with bootstrap", not sure what you mean there pal, but i'm using bootstrap, materializecss without any issue. Check out my tutorial here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLJNOthdZG8

Comment: @sangram, thanks for the comment. In your example, you are mainly using native HTML elements on which you are applying your CSS. I was referring to applying an external CSS library like Bootstrap to native Lightning ui components like <ui:inputCheckbox> or <ui:button> that already have their own default styles.

Comment: @Daniel, inspect element for <ui:button> via chrome gives me a button and a span inside that button. Lightning has assigned some classes to this component. Perhaps those classes could be removed or overridden by bootstrap class using javascript or css. This could be another video for my youtube channel. Shall get back to you if i succeed.

Comment: There's something called $A.util.addClass(), $A.util.removeClass(), and $A.util.toggleClass(). Override the platform css using rendered. Use on init event. Follow these links. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_show_hide_markup.htm  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_dom_access.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will recommend not to style it with bootstrap instead use [lightning design system](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/). So, that your component looks consistent with rest of the app. However, if you wan to use bootstrap use

```
<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.resourceName}" />
```

or if you want to use multiple file then

```
styles="{!join(',', 
    $Resource.myStyles + '/stylesheetOne.css', 
    $Resource.myStyles + '/moreStyles.css')}"
```

Please refer to following [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apps_css_external_platform.htm) for more information.

Comment: Yes I agree. When I created this post, Lightning Design System had not been released yet and Lightning itself wasn't GA.